# Wikipedia: How to activate email notification from watchlist?

Tags: wikipedia, email

I may have a blackout on this, so please help.

I have a wikipedia account with a confirmed email. I have checked the box "Email me when a page or file on my watchlist is changed".

I have two pages on my watchlist:
1. a page I edited
2. my sandbox page

I have visited my sandbox page several times and edited it. But I have not received any notification emails.

What did I do wrong?

This is one [instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Email_notification) that I believe I have followed:

> *If your Preferences has "Email me when a page or file on my watchlist is changed" set, then only by visiting a page will you actually set
>   its email notification flag.
>
> Once you miss the email for a particular page change or don't visit
>   the page (or ignore the email), you will not receive any more emails
>   for that page. You can still dutifully monitor that page by its
>   watchlist edit-summaries, but its particular email notification flag
>   will remain unset until you visit it. This facilitates monitoring a
>   large watchlist while preventing potentially useless emails to you.*

Comment: Casual comment: I don't believe wp sends emails anymore (would bog down the server too much), but you might see if ifttt.com can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried the mail feature, but I think MediaWiki notifies you when somebody else edits the page. There is no reason to send you a mail when you edit the page yourself - you should already know that you have edited it.

If you want to make sure that it works, you can try adding an often edited page and check if you are getting mail daily - for example, articles on the present and previous presidents of the United States could make a good benchmarks these days, because they are getting a lot of editions a day.

Comment: I just received an email notification regarding an edit of a page on my watch list. Your answer is correct. Thanks.